# Sending data to different domain via JSONP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm using AngularJS's $http, and I'm trying to send a `GET` (JSONP in fact, which is basically a GET) to a different domain, and also send some data inside the `data` member ( http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http ) but I'm not really sure that's possible. Is it?

Comment: You can send data using JSONP only via the query string.  The request will always be a GET with an empty body.